# Oracle TO_DATE: Works in SELECT; Not a Valid Month in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, crystal-reports

I've written a query that consists of 2 subqueries.  The subqueries format the resulting field names and data types so they are identical.  The main query is a straight UNION.

Both subqueries retrieve data from a hosted Oracle server; we have no control over the database structure.  One of the two subqueries uses a string data type to contain a DateTime.  I am using the following code in the SELECT to convert the value to DateTime and add 2 hours to adjust for time zones:

```
TO_DATE(TCF.TRANS_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24 AS TRANS_DT,
```

This produces the correct value.

Here's the wrinkle: An identical TO_DATE in the WHERE clause produces the error ORA-01843: not a valid month.  Here is the complete WHERE clause:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(TCF.TRANS_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24 >= {?START_DT}
```

The obvious question is why is the above working in the SELECT but throwing this error in the WHERE clause?

The value in the field is formatted as specified in the TO_DATE statement.  Were it not I would expect the SELECT statement to produce the error, but there is no error when the WHERE clause is removed.

I have tried adding a TRUNC() to the WHERE clause since the parameter {?START_DT} is a Date data type.  i have also hard-coded a valid date in lieu of using the parameter.  Neither of these had any affect on the error.

Completing the WHERE clause for the second subquery is all that remains for me to complete this project and move along.  I am using Crystal Reports with a mature and reliable connection to access the database.  Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

For your information, here is the entire query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TCF.TRIPCARD_UNIT_NO AS UNIT_NO,
TO_DATE(TCF.TRANS_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TRANS_DT2,
TCF.ODOMETER AS METER
FROM MFIVE.VIEW_TRIPCARD_FAILED_TRANS TCF
WHERE TO_DATE(TCF.TRANS_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= TO_DATE('02-01-2019 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Out of frustration I parsed the month, day and year values from the TRANS_DT string.  There were no values out of proper range; specifically ALL months were values between 1 and 12 as expected.

I created a new TO_DATE statement in the WHERE clause against the above concatenated parts.  Checked and double-checked the formatting...and I got the same error.

It appears to me that TO_DATE isn't allowed in the WHERE clause.  Has anyone else heard of this restriction?  Any way to create a DateTime variable within the SQL and pass that to the WHERE clause?

UPDATE #3:

Leaving the WHERE clause omitted I used the rest of the query as a subquery and used EXTRACT MONTH FROM TRANS_DT for the SELECT statement.  This subquery ran beautifully and produced on whole numbers from 1 to 12.  This confirms again there are NO malformed dates involved.

Extending the subquery concept I attempted to apply the WHERE clause with this statement: `WHERE TRUNC(TCF2.TRANS_DT) >= TO_DATE('02/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`  This produced the same error!  I'm smelling a bug, but damned if I know what it is.

Comment: What is TCF.TRANS_DATE column's datatype?

Comment: @Littlefoot:  TCF.TRANS_DATE is the string datatype that I mentioned.

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(TCF.TRANS_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM <whatever the table name is> TCF`? If that errors (as I'm pretty sure it will) then you have malformed data, and without the `where` it works for one of the reasons Gordon gave. (This is one of the major reasons storing dates as strings is bad, but from you 'no control' comment I guess you know that already!)

Comment: @Alex:  Sorry, no error returned from your query.  It returned today's date, which is the correct result for the query.  To your point though, if I have malformed data...why doesn't the SELECT clause throw the error in the absence of the WHERE clause?  (And yes, this is quite the Frankenstein table.  Exceptionally poor design.)

Comment: @spacetanker - if it was malformed, then what Gordon said; but it doesn't seem to be. Are you sure `{?START_DT}` and the fixed value you tried were actually dates, not strings relying on implicit conversion? Also are there other similar 'date' comparisons elsewhere? It's possible that adding that one as a filter is changing the execution plan, and those are now being evaluated in a different order. Check both execution plans and see what changed.

Comment: Hmm, have you added the `WHERE` clause in the subquery, or in the main query? If the you added it to the main query, and the subquery is itself aliased as `TCF`, then you'd be doing implicit conversion which could easily cause this. Showing more of your code would be helpful.

Comment: @Alex:  To your second recent comment, I have isolated and simplified the second query to make troubleshooting less cumbersome.  To your other comment, the parameters are dates, but I have replaced them with with a specified date in the query, trying to eliminate possible issues.  I have also posted the entire SQL statement as it currently exists in the original question.

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where the `MAX()` would work and return the correct latest date, but that simplified query would throw ORA-01843. Interesting.

Comment: @Alex:  I agree.  I'm at the beat my head against the desk point with this.  Such a simple query, too!  If the database takes exception with the TO_DATE statement it should do so consistently.  At present it doesn't appear to be doing that.  Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two likely reasons:

First, you are running the query but only looking at a few rows of results -- not the entire result set.  The rows that you see do not have a problem with the date.  If you scrolled to the end, then you would see the problem.

The second reason is that the `select` expressions are run after *all* filtering (at least in some cases).  The bad values may be filtered out by other filtering conditions.  When the expression is moved to the `where` clause, all the data might be passed through this condition.

Comment: When I run the query without the WHERE clause, essentially no constraints, all of the data is successfully processed by the TO_DATE statement in SELECT clause.I did a more thorough check after seeing your remarks and do not see any obvious issues.  Of course it goes without saying there were no errors.

Good point on the order of operations.  I had not considered that, but the only filtering is the aforementioned WHERE clause consisting of that single filter condition.  Without it, it runs.  With it, it errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the datatype when equating or matching:

```
WITH S_DT AS 
(
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') START_DT FROM DUAL
),
TAB AS
(
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24 AS TRANS_DT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 2/24 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'MM-DD-YYYY') + 2/24 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM TAB,S_DT WHERE TAB.TRANS_DT >= S_DT.START_DT;
```

Output:

```
TRANS_DT  START_DT 
--------- ---------
2/22/2019 2:09:39 PM    2/22/2019 12:09:39 PM
```

OR, you can also try this `NEW_TIME` function for `time zone` change.

```
SELECT SYSDATE, 
       NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'EST') 
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
SYSDATE   NEW_TIME(SYSDATE,'GMT','EST')
--------- -----------------------------
2/22/2019 12:10:10 PM   2/22/2019 7:10:10 AM
```

Comment: I have checked the datatype.  I know that TRANS_DT is a String and of the form 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'.  TO_DATE in the SELECT clause works without exception.  Unless I'm missing something you were attempting to illustrate in your example.  That said, I removed the time zone correction from my code and it still runs without the WHERE clause and errors when it is included.  Points for the time zone function; I have not seen that before.